# How can I retrieve a package and use its executables/components to be attached to added components in EzAPI?

Tags: templates, ssis, ezapi

I have a package, containing a container, loaded from a file. I want to attach a new component to the container with EzAPI.
The component was added with the EzAPI, now I only have to retrieve the name of the container in the package to attach it.

How can I retrieve the name of the containercomponent in EzAPI?

```
        // Load template package.
        package.LoadFromFile("Package.dtsx");
        // I hoped with one of these for loops to retrieve the name of a component within the template package.
        foreach (var ezEx in package.Executables)
        {
        }
        foreach (var ezEx in package.EzExecs)
        {
        }
        // This component should be connected to a component of the template package.
        var truncateTableTask = new EzExecSqlTask(package)
        {
            Name = "EST Truncate Table",
            Connection = destConn,
            SqlStatementSource = " TRUNCATE TABLE " + destinationTableName
        };
```

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Answer (score 1):

While I'm waiting to hear back on the *details* of what your code looks like, feel free to look at my assorted postings on EzAPI. Of particular interest, [sequence containers and precedence constraints](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2012/02/sequence-containers-and-precedence.html) covers all of this.

It boils down to either using the **AttachTo** method like 
`objA.AttachTo(objB)` or if you need to fiddle with the precedence constraint, go with the **Add** method to an object's PrecedenceConstraints collection like `executableObject.PrecedenceConstraints.Add(objA, objB)`

## Edit 0

Given your sample code and the comments within, I think the problem you are running into is that the EzAPI gets really confused when there is presentation data in an SSIS package. The object model itself has no spatial awareness. If I add a Data Flow task into a package, I don't specify where the object should be drawn on the canvas. That's an unfortunate artifact of using VS to develop packages. To make this layout stuff work, behind the scenes, VS serializes all of this layout data and writes it into a node of the SSIS package. <sup>*Insert yo dawg meme about using XML to store XML.</sup>

So, the layout data is not needed for a package to run and otherwise really fouls up EzAPI. Your options then become strip the presentation data out *or* forgo using the EzAPI and just work with the bare metal (base libraries).

Stripping the presentation stuff is covered by Josh Robinson's article [Editing Existing SSIS Package via EzAPI or Standard SSIS API Doesn’t Update Layout in BIDS](http://joshrobi.blogspot.com/2012/04/editing-existing-ssis-package-via-ezapi.html) and will make your life easier.

### To the pain

I generated a sample package with a single sequence container using Biml. Not required but this allows future readers to follow along.

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <!-- Change ConnectionString below. Privider if not 2012, Data Source for certain -->
        <OleDbConnection
            Name="destConn"
            ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost\dev2012;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;"
            />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package
            Name="20095907_ezapi"
            ConstraintMode="Linear">
            <!--
            CREATE TABLE dbo.[20095907_ezapi]
            (
                MyColumn int NULL
            );
            -->
            <Connections>
                <Connection ConnectionName="destConn"/>
            </Connections>
            <Variables>
                <Variable Name="destinationTableName" DataType="String">dbo.[20095907_ezapi]</Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <Container
                    Name="MyCleverContainer"
                    ConstraintMode="Linear"
                    >
                </Container>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Armed with a package I then spent my lunch hour mucking about with the object model. The core problem is that you need to be able to call either `truncateTableTask.AttachTo(seq);` where seq is in the Ez object domain or you need to get the base Executable version of truncateTableTask to call `PrecedenceConstraints.Add(seq, truncateTableTaskBase)`

Below are my **incomplete** fumblings to do so. Posting it now so that you have some code at least to work with along with the explanation of why things are as they are.

```
    public static void soFix()
    {
        string sourceFile = @"C:\Users\bfellows\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Demo\Demo\20095907_ezapi.dtsx";
        EzPackage package = null;
        EzOleDbConnectionManager destConn = null;
        string destinationTableName = "dbo.[20095907_ezapi]";

        package = new EzPackage();
        package.LoadFromFile(sourceFile);

        destConn = new EzOleDbConnectionManager(package, package.Connections["destConn"]);
        bool foundSomething = false;

        // This component should be connected to a component of the template package.
        var truncateTableTask = new EzExecSqlTask(package)
        {
            Name = "EST Truncate Table",
            Connection = destConn,
            SqlStatementSource = " TRUNCATE TABLE " + destinationTableName
        };


        Executable fromObject = null;
        Executable toObject = null;

        // I hoped with one of these for loops to retrieve the name of a component within the template package.
        foreach (Executable item in package.Executables)
        {
            // http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.eventsprovider.aspx
            // This enumerates items using the base object types
            // They will either be a TaskHost or a container type
            //      Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ForEachLoop
            //      Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.ForLoop
            //      Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Sequence                

            TaskHost outer = item as TaskHost;
            TaskHost inner = item as TaskHost;

            Sequence seq = item as Sequence;
            ForLoop fl = item as ForLoop;
            ForEachLoop fel = item as ForEachLoop;

            if (seq != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", seq.GetType(), seq.Name));
                toObject = item;
            }

            if (fl != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", fl.GetType(), fl.Name));

            }
            if (fel != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", fel.GetType(), fel.Name));

            }

            // Task examples
            // Here is where you would test the executable's type to determine if it's what you're looking for
            if (inner != null)
            {
                if (inner.InnerObject is Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.MainPipe)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("I haz DFT");
                }

                if (inner.InnerObject is Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ExecuteSQLTask.ExecuteSQLTask)
                {
                    Executable exec = item;
                    if (outer.ID == truncateTableTask.ID)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("We are looking at the object we just created");
                        fromObject = item;
                    }
                    ExecuteSQLTask tmp = (ExecuteSQLTask)inner.InnerObject;
                    Console.WriteLine("I haz execute SQL Task");
                }


            }

        }

        // package.EzExecs.Count showing 0?
        // The layout XML does not play nicely with EzAPI
        // http://joshrobi.blogspot.com/2012/04/editing-existing-ssis-package-via-ezapi.html
        foreach (var ezEx in package.EzExecs)
        {
            // this enumerates items using the EZ object types
            Console.WriteLine(ezEx);
            Console.WriteLine(ezEx.EzName);
        }

        // Attach my execute sql task as a preceding executable
        // However, since we're in classic object land, ezapi won't help
        Package classic = new Package();
        classic.LoadFromXML(package.SaveToXML(), null);

        try
        {
            PrecedenceConstraint pc = null;
            pc = classic.PrecedenceConstraints.Add(fromObject as Executable, toObject as Executable);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            throw;
        }

        Application app = new Application();
        app.SaveToXml(sourceFile, classic, null);

    }
```

Comment: I have posted the code in the question, the problem is that I do not know objB which is within the template package.

Comment: Updated with some help. Note that the `classic.PrecedenceConstraints.Add` is currently failing but I've run out of time to research further.